# How to grep literal match in list of domains

Tags: shell-script, grep, busybox

I have a hosts file full of hosts, like so:

```
127.0.0.1 home-domain.net
127.0.0.1 here.home-domain.net
127.0.0.1 home-domain.netn
127.0.0.1 home.domain.net
127.0.0.1 home.domain.net.some
```

In an ash shell script (BusyBox), I only want literal match(es), I have

```
match=home.domain.net
grep " $match$" file
```

This correctly matches "home.domain.net", but also "home-domain.net"
The space I use in " $match$" is to limit it to the beginning of the host name, while the $ is the line end.
How can I only match the literal of "home.domain.net"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I only match the literal of "home.domain.net"?

You need to escape the `.` characters using `\`. Then the only special regexp character is the second `$`.

```
match=home\.domain\.net
grep " $match$" file
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
127.0.0.1 home-domain.net
127.0.0.1 here.home-domain.net
127.0.0.1 home-domain.netn
127.0.0.1 home.domain.net
127.0.0.1 home.domain.net.some
$ match=home\.domain\.net
$ grep " $match$" file
127.0.0.1 home-domain.net
127.0.0.1 home.domain.net
```

Note:

- `127.0.0.1 home-domain.net` is repeated in your example host file.

Source [grep](https://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) - Search file(s) for specific text.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [grep](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) - Search file(s) for specific text.

Comment: Escaping all dots is not possible, that would mean I'd have to do it first on a file 20MB large of hosts, then do the search for it and remove the slashes again as this file is in use.

Comment: @stargazer You misunderstand. You need to escape the `.` in the **search string** not the hosts file.

Comment: Got it, thanks. This works perfect: grep " $(echo $match | sed 's/\./\\./g')$"